# How to prevent <video> from restarting after parameter update

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering

I have a universal React app that shows an autoplaying video tag. When the javascript loads, React subsumes it but that restarts the video from the beginning.

Is there a way to prevent this?

This can also be reproduced with hot reloading, since that also updates the DOM.